# I'm not a Muslim and I had a dream of church and a mosque

Tags: non-muslim, conversion

I was inside a building that was like a mall; and I noticed that there was church and a mosque. On the outside they really didn't look like religious houses; however, I believe it was God who was talking to me asking me to pick the path that I want to follow. I want to make sure that I am on the path of God's will. May you please give me Quranic verses that support that Islam is the true religion? Note: I downloaded a free version of the Holy Quran in pdf document for my ereader which has both Arabic and English translation. So far my prayer is for Him to show me the truth and have it be compared to the Bible.

Comment: I suggest that you take your time and read the Qur'an that you downloaded, you will definitely feel something different.

Comment: Okay, I will be guided by the Lord to understand what is truth or untruth. If God shows me that the Quran is true. I will convert.

Comment: As long as you are seeking the truth sincerely, you will find it.

Comment: I have a feeling about the Quran and maybe God is trying to show me something. I had multiple dreams where God would answer my prayers.

Comment: "So, whomsoever Allah wills to guide, He makes his heart wide open for Islam, and whomsoever He wills to let go astray, He makes his heart strait and constricted, (and he feels embracing Islam as difficult) as if he were climbing to the sky. In this way, Allah lays abomination on those who do not believe." Qur'an[6:125]

Comment: By the way I am Christian. I was watching an animated movie about the prophet Muhammad and it was basically about Mecca and how there was idolatry and that God sent His prophet.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_tjxz4yS_U

Comment: the link is something i thought as beautiful

Comment: Also check this http://www.islamreligion.com/articles/216/quran-on-human-embryonic-development/

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-top-ten-verses-in-Holy-Quran-that-would-enlighten-a-non-moslem

( There are other similar questions on quora, you can also give them a look)
Also try to find an educated Muslim and have her/him guide you on your  journey and answer questions you have. Quran is full of good quotes and but also has few lines where you need someone who know's Islamic history and Arabic and has been acquainted with Quran; not many are such! And never forget to ask Allah to guide you constantly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> May you please give me Quranic verses that support that Islam is the
>   true religion?

Acccording to Surah Al-i-Imran (3:19):

إِنَّ الدِّينَ عِندَ اللَّـهِ الْإِسْلَامُ ۗ وَمَا اخْتَلَفَ الَّذِينَ أُوتُوا الْكِتَابَ إِلَّا مِن بَعْدِ مَا جَاءَهُمُ الْعِلْمُ بَغْيًا بَيْنَهُمْ ۗ وَمَن يَكْفُرْ بِآيَاتِ اللَّـهِ فَإِنَّ اللَّـهَ سَرِيعُ الْحِسَابِ

"*Indeed, the religion in the sight of Allah is Islam. And those who were given the Scripture did not differ except after knowledge had come to them - out of jealous animosity between themselves. And whoever disbelieves in the verses of Allah, then indeed, Allah is swift in [taking] account.*"
([Quran translation](http://tanzil.net/#3:19), 3:19)

Comment: Truly, the Lord is showing me something.

Comment: @jvjurad, with your permission, I added its Arabic Quranic verse to your nice answer to  make more helpful (although it was helpful by itself).